# Glitch in Customer's Billing address in admin panel

Tags: magento2, customer-address

I can see The first name and last name of the customer in Billing and shipping address is coming in the form of code.
Please see https://prnt.sc/yezZ9OBC4C-t

Can anyone help me in resolving this, and how can i avoid this in future

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel go to `Store > Configuration > Customer > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address Templates` and check HTML conditions, I think someone modified this and because of that this issue has occurred

[image]

Comment: but this is not occurring for all orders. It just happened for one

Comment: And this is coming for its first name and last name in address